# Pandas -change id to string using map and lambda

Tags: pandas

with this dictionary:

```
   teams_dict = {'Tottenham':262, 'Liverpool': 263, 'Leeds': 264}
```

And having a column 'team_id' in `df1` and a column 'team_name' in another `df2`, how do I change id to name in `df1`, using `map()` and `lambda` in `pandas`?

I've tried:

```
df1['team_name'] = df2['team_name'].map(lambda x: teams_dict[x])
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Try this:  `teams_dict_r = {v:k for k, v in teams_dict.items()}` then `df1['team_name'] = df1['team_id'].map(teams_dict_r)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply` instead of `map`:

```
df1['team_name'] = df2['team_name'].apply(lambda x: teams_dict[x])
```

It's worth mentioning that this is index-agnostic and only works if df1 and df2 are the same size, and are sorted the same way.